# What is the meaning of the dot in SQL from statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say we have a simple query

```
SELECT something
FROM name_before_dot.name_after_dot
```

What is the meaning of the dot in the FROM clause?

Is it some kind of separator or is it just a table name with the dot in it?

Mind you, I have already searched SO, its threads were talking about dot in select or where, which I know are related to aliases, dot in from is still a mystery to me.

Comment: `[schema_name].[table_name]`

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?, different ones have different names for it

Comment: @Lamak It's Oracle

Comment: @David Thank you, please write as answer and I will approve it.

Comment: bow down before the dot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a database schema. Full three-part name of a table is:

```
databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

For a default schema of the user, you can also omit the schema name:

```
databasename..tablename
```

You can also specify a linked server name:

```
servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

You can read more about using identifiers as table names on [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx):

The server, database, and owner names are known as the qualifiers of the object name. When you refer to an object, you do not have to specify the server, database, and owner. The qualifiers can be omitted by marking their positions with a period. The valid forms of object names include the following:

> server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name
>
> server_name.database_name..object_name
>
> server_name..schema_name.object_name
>
> server_name...object_name
>
> database_name.schema_name.object_name
>
> database_name..object_name
>
> schema_name.object_name
>
> object_name

An object name that specifies all four parts is known as a fully qualified name. Each object that is created in Microsoft SQL Server must have a unique, fully qualified name. For example, there can be two tables named xyz in the same database if they have different owners.

Most object references use three-part names. The default server_name is the local server. The default database_name is the current database of the connection. The default schema_name is the default schema of the user submitting the statement. Unless otherwise configured, the default schema of new users is the dbo schema.

Comment: Approved as more detailed answer.

Comment: No such thing as "server_name" in an object name in Oracle, and you can't have two dots (`..`) like that.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT something
FROM name_before_dot.name_after_d
```

if you literally Translate

```
select <column_name>
from <schema_name>.<table_name>
```

Comment: I approved the other answer as more detailed, but here is a bonus from me, thank you =)

Answer (score 2):

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51132) explains this in some detail.

[image]

> where:
>
> - object is the name of the object.
> - schema is the schema containing the object. The schema qualifier lets you refer to an object in a schema other than your own. You must be granted privileges to refer to objects in other schemas. If you omit schema, then Oracle assumes that you are referring to an object in your own schema.
>     ...

so with only two parts as you've shown, in `from` clause, the `name_before_dot` is the schema the object is in (i.e. its owner), and `name_after_dot` is the object name.

You can see the owner and object names in the `all_objects` view.